# HTML/CSS - Position 2 blocks in a independant way

Tags: html, css

I've two elements in my fieldset, each of them placed in a div. What I wanted to do is to choose their position in the fieldset without impacting the position of the other element. Here's what I'm doing :

http://jsfiddle.net/ALUTp/

I though that with the `position : absolute`, it would be enough but apperently it isn't.

Any idea?

Comment: You can set a `position: relative` to the `fieldset` and position the `div`'s `absolute`. They will be absolute positioned relative to the `fieldset`.

Comment: Your fiddle shows nothing positioned absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` and it will take the elements out of flow like you're wanting, but you have to make a few changes first.  First, you need to assign a parent that the `position:absolute` elements will base their position on (I assume the fieldset).  You do this by giving it the attribute `position:relative`.  `fixed` and `absolute` work to, but `relative` doesn't affect the element's position or flow (unless you also add `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` attributes).  It just can't be the default, `position:static`.  Next, the container will collapse (because the `div`s are out of flow when they are `position:absolute`), so you have to give your parent container, which is the `fieldset`, a height or give it other elements that are not out of flow and give it dimension. Lastly, you need to swap your `margin` attributes for the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` attributes, and you're done.

All that put together looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/swC2w/

```
fieldset {
    height: 250px;
    position : relative;
}

#first {
    top: 90px;
    position : absolute;

}

#second {
    position : absolute;
    left : 290px;
    bottom : 190px;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `position: absolute`, you have to set `position: relative` on the parent element. Otherwise the absolute positions are in relation to body element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9R6/

```
fieldset {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 90%;
}
#first {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 30px;
}
#second {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```